# Maintaining a Queue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-structures

I am working and MVC4 and Return a list of objects to View as Json. Actually View makes a Ajax call to Controller to retrieve data. I need to maintain a Queue of that Object and Display them on my page in such a way each object will be displayed for 10 secs and then it will be replaced with second object in Queue. I am using following code to make an Ajax call

```
function GetData() {
    $.get("http://localhost:45533/Home/GetData/", function (data) {
        ProcessData(data);
        // Here i need to add [data] to Queue
    });
}

function ProcessData(data) {
    $("#myDiv").append(data.Name+ "<br/>");
}

$("#fetchBtn").click(function() {
    // Here i need to get the next object in data from Queue
});
```

Currently i am using button click to refresh it. Can anyone suggest how i can maintain a Queue of returned data?

Comment: Look at `array.push()` and `array.shift()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var arData = [];

function GetData() {
    $.get("http://localhost:45533/Home/GetData/", function (data) {
        ProcessData(data);
        // Here i need to add [data] to Queue
    });
}

function ProcessData(data) {
    arData.push(data)   //  add it to the end of the array
    $("#myDiv").append(data.Name+ "<br/>");
}

$("#fetchBtn").click(function() {
    // Here i need to get the next object in data from Queue
    var data = arData.shift();  //  get the first item of the array
});
```

`arData.push(data)` adds `data` to the end of the array, while `arData.shift()` returns the first item in the array and removes it at the same time.

Comment: Lol at the -1 that has no reason for it.  This is exactly what was asked for.

Comment: I have not done anything with -1? Perhaps while looking at your code it got clicked somehow

Comment: Don't worry mate - I didn't think it was you.  I upset someone last week by disagreeing with them and they've been serial-downvoting me ever since.  Admin are awarding me the points back anyway.